# Redux with a large entities in a state

Tags: redux, immutable.js

I have a redux application. In a first load (initial state) I get data from server  and put it into the store. Application have entity with name "Task". If this tasks about 500 - app work perfectly (fast). But if tasks over 2000 - I see a slow down work. This "tasks" use a differents areas.
May I optimize my application? I don't want call API for different areas because this areas use a similar "tasks".
I read about immutable.js. This is may way or not?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Without seeing your code it is really hard to give suggestions

Comment: Thanks for reply. But this only architecture question. I imaging the store as a database. And all manipulations - only "filter" actions.

Comment: Would you really have 2000 tasks simultaneously on the screen? It rather sounds you are doing premature optimizations, if it is just a thought process, you won't know until you coded it first. Depending on your design, you should be able to tweak your solution if it really is to slow

Comment: No. On the screen user see maximum 150 tasks (for current project). But other tasks (from other projects) may be located in other areas on the current screen (for example, "important" tasks or "notifications" tasks).  Of course, I may call API for this areas (important,notifications). But get tasks from one store ("single source of true") - is more simple variant. Not?

Comment: I guess it really depends on how you design the store you have in mind

Comment: This is analog of trello. We have a one main screen with tasks for current board.Also, we have a other areas on the screen - "important tasks", "notifications tasks". And this tasks may be from other boards. The scheme is very simple, but filtering over 2000 tasks - is a very slow.

Comment: It all depends on the shape of your tasks, your store and how you manipulate them and where. Can we see some code, like the shape of the task object, some reducer, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual number of entities or JS objects in the store shouldn't matter in and of itself - it's a question of what your code is *doing* with those entities.  If you're doing expensive transformations or filtering options every time your components re-render, then yes, an increase in the number of entities will slow things down.  Also, using Immutable won't magically improve speed - it can make certain operations faster, but has overhead of its own and can be misused.

I'll point you to some resources for improving Redux performance:

- My blog post [Practical Redux, Part 6: Connected Lists, Forms, and Performance](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-6-connected-lists-forms-and-performance/)
- A slideshow called [High Performance Redux](http://somebody32.github.io/high-performance-redux/)
- The articles in the [Redux Performance](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-performance.md#redux-performance) section of my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links)
- The [Redux FAQ entry on "scaling" Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Performance.html#performance-scaling)
- The [Redux FAQ entry on speeding up `mapState` functions](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-mapstate-speed)

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is a very helpful links for me. My purpose - not call API for different areas (important tasks area, notifications tasks area), but get this tasks from one source - store (simple filtering it by field "important", "notification"). And yes, I change this tasks (for example - sorting) and mutate store (state = "tasks"). If I simple update my store - I override this tasks state (2000 objects).